# Transfer a repository from one user account to another user account

Tags: git, github

I have two accounts on GitHub. I want to transfer one of my repositories from one account to another. I don't want to fork the repository, but to completely transfer its ownership. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to your repository's settings (*not* your account settings), scroll down (under options) until you see a panel entitled *Danger Zone*.

[image]

For more info, see [Transferring a repository owned by your personal account](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-personal-account/).